# Will mobile apps running meteor 1.1 still work if the server is updated to 1.2?

Tags: cordova, meteor, modulus

I've updated locally to 1.2 and the app runs well; if I deploy this local build to modulus and I still have lots of mobile cordova clients out there running older code, will they all still work together?

I'm guessing a big update like this won't work as a hot code push to the clients? :P

Comment: Nobody can answer you at this point since Meteor 1.2 was released today, you should check https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI

Comment: How did you get on? I have the same issue looming...

Comment: Since I hadn't changed any functionality and only upgraded meteor itself, I've left it until I either find an answer or need to take the plunge...